# Creating a RDS PostgreSQL slave in different account on same region

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, database-replication

I have a master RDS postgreSQL in one account and I would like to create a slave in a different account and replication enabled(either sync or async), both master-slave can be in different AZ, but on same region only.

Can you please suggest if its possible to do so in AWS. Any pointers or links would be helpful.

Comment: When you say 'slave', are you referring to a [read replica for Amazon RDS for PostgreSQL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_PostgreSQL.Replication.ReadReplicas.html)? Why do you need it to be in a different AWS Account?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein yes i meant to say read replica. I need the replica to be created in different account to be used for analytical purpose with different billing team

Comment: Why not just give them a login to the existing PostgreSQL database? Database logins are not associated with AWS Accounts.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein yes, but this is not our requirement at this point.